# 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<Users 0x78eb5bf0> valueForUndefinedKey:]: the entity Users is not key value coding-compliant for the key "James".'

Tags: swift, core-data

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here :/

What I want is to be able to get all the data stored in the core data attributes within an entity by a given name.

So for example, all the info stored about the user "James".

Here is my code:

```
func getUserDetails(name: String) {
    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Users")

    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
    do {
        let result = try context.fetch(request)
        for data in result as! [NSManagedObject] {
            print(data.value(forKey: name) as! String)
        }

    } catch {

        print("Failed")
    }
}
```

I am setting this info like so:

```
func parseJson() {
        let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Users", in: context)
        let user = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: context)

        Alamofire.request(jsonLocation).responseJSON { (responseData) -> Void in
            if((responseData.result.value) != nil) {
                let swiftyJsonVar = JSON(responseData.result.value!)


                for (_, value) in swiftyJsonVar {

                    let name = value["name"].stringValue
                    let gender = value["gender"].stringValue
                    let age = value["age"].intValue

                    user.setValue(name, forKey: "name")
                    user.setValue(gender, forKey: "gender")
                    user.setValue(age, forKey: "age")

                    do {
                        try context.save()
                    } catch {
                        print("Failed saving")
                    }

                }
            }
        }
}
```

but the error I am getting is:

> 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ valueForUndefinedKey:]: the entity Users is not key value coding-compliant for the key "James".'

Any ideas?

P.s. This is in a class called UserDetails. before the functions for the class but still in the class scope I have set:

```
let jsonLocation = "https://link.to/json/for/users"
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
```

Comment: Where is your class UserDetail ? The error seem to be coming from there.

Comment: Can you just reinstall app again and check?

Answer (score 0):

The method `getUserDetails()` causes the issue.

In the line

```
print(data.value(forKey: name) as! String)
```

you are getting the attribute for the passed parameter string (rather than literal `"name"`) but there is no attribute `James` in the model.

You have to add a predicate to filter the records whose `name` is `James` and print the value for the literal string `"name"`

```
func getUserDetails(name: String) {
    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Users")
    request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name == %@", name)

    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
    do {
        let result = try context.fetch(request) as! [NSManagedObject]
        for data in result {
            print(data.value(forKey: "name") as! String)
        }

    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

---

Note:

It's highly recommended to use a `NSManagedObject` subclass to have more convenient access to the attributes. It avoids that kind of errors. And I recommend also to use more descriptive variable names.

```
 func getUserDetails(name: String) {
    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let request = NSFetchRequest<Users>(entityName: "Users")
    request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name == %@", name)

    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
    do {
        let users = try context.fetch(request)
        for user in users {
            print(user.name)
        }

    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am new to coredata and I am struggling a lot it appears. Can I ask, is the predicate basically a Where close?

Comment: Great. that clears it up slightly. When I run the function nothing happens. I am running it in the viewdidload(). I thought maybe it is because the data is coming from a JSON file on the internet and if I add the code to the end of the alamofire function it works. I thought it was supposed to persist?

Comment: An Alamofire request works asynchronously. The data is returned later in the completion block.

Comment: yes, but then once it is done, that means the data is stored right? so the next time I open my app, even before alamofire has run, the data is there to get? This is why I am getting confused

Comment: P.s Thank you for your help with this. Very much appreciated.